# Problema al publicar una aplicación que contiene SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una aplicación en ASP.NET MVC la cual incorpora librerias para manipular SignalR y realizar un chat en una de las páginas de la aplicación. El problema con el que me encuentro es que al debuguear la aplicación funciona de manera correcta, pero al publicar en IIS la funcionalidad del chat no funciona y no logro resolver el porqué a ésto.

El código jQuery que utilizo para manipular SignalR:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.-->
<script>
    $(function () {
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
        // Create a function that the hub can call back to display messages.
        chat.client.addNewMessageToPage = function (name, message) {
            // Add the message to the page.
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message[0]) + '</li>');
            $('#discussion2').append('<li><strong>' + htmlEncode(name)
                + '</strong>: ' + htmlEncode(message[1]) + '</li>');
        };
        // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
        $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
        // Set initial focus to message input box.
        $('#message').focus();
        // Start the connection.
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                // Call the Send method on the hub.
                chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment.
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            });
        });
    });
    // This optional function html-encodes messages for display in the page.
    function htmlEncode(value) {
        var encodedValue = $('<div />').text(value).html();
        return encodedValue;
    }
</script>
```

El código que utilizo en el ChatHub (Concentrador de SignalR) para llamar a la funcion:

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        // Call the addNewMessageToPage method to update clients.
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
```

La aplicación cuenta con el archivo Startup.cs para inicializar el mapeo a signalr:

[image: Explorador de soluciones de la aplicación]

Espero haber sido claro, soy nuevo en la comunidad de Stack asi que sepan disculpar si me falta claridad en la pregunta.

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: del lado del cliente cual error obtienes , si tienes chrome presiona f12 y revisa la consola, tambien como armas el paquete de instalacion cuando lo hagas asegurate que incluyes los paquetes de tu aplicacion ejemplo Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb es necesario para signalr, estas publicando en iis express?

Comment: Estaba trabajando en un sistema de Notificaciones en tiempo real con SignalR y me he tropezado con el mismo problema, en development funciona perfectamente pero al publicarlo en IIS no se por que motivo se caen todos los intentos de conexiones websocket, sse, etc. Sin embargo al publicar solamente con kestrel esto no ocurre, por lo que parece ser algo con IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Lo he solucionado de la siguiente manera:

En el Panel de control, click en Agregar o quitar características de Windows. Despliega Internet Information Services / Servicios de World Wide Web / Application Development Features y activar Websocker Protocol. con esta activado ya funciona Websocket de SiganlR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]